# Drupal form continues to get submitted even if jQuery submit() function returns false;

Tags: jquery, forms, drupal, drupal-6, validation

I have a Drupal form,

```
<form action="/forms/contact.html"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="webform-client-form-1148-1" class="webform-client-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

with the following submit,

```
<input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit-1" value="Submit"  class="form-submit" />
```

The page containing the form loads the following jQuery inline,

```
jQuery("#webform-client-form-1148-1").submit(function(){return false;});
```

No matter what I try, the submit button always submits the form.  Since I am returning false, I expect the form to disregard the submission process and cancel completely.

**Why does the form continue to submit, even though 'return false' is being returned for the form's submit() function?**

This is a simple example that I have dumbed down in my code to force submit on the form to always return false, and therefore, should never submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a similar question not long ago. Check [Stop form from submitting when searching with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701752/stop-form-from-submitting-when-searching-with-jquery/6701788#6701788)

Solution is to apply the `event.preventDefault()` event method.  Don't forget to pass the event through the function.

e.g.

```
jQuery("#webform-client-form-1148-1").submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Based off of debugging and following the code path into jQuery, invoking 'return false' should call event.preventDefault downstream in jQuery core code.  Here is a link to a post online that has also touches on this topic, http://css-tricks.com/6809-return-false-and-prevent-default/.

Comment: Good point Mike!  That link mentions the following, which goes into more details http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ , great read!

Answer (score 1):

remove `input type="submit"`

```
<input type="button" name="op" id="edit-submit-1" value="Submit"  class="form-submit" />
```

and the try this..

```
$('#edit-submit-1').click(function(){
        jQuery("#webform-client-form-1148-1").submit(function(){return false;});

});
```

if you don't want to submit your form at all then you can use [**unbind()**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or [**die()**](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

you can use `event.preventDefault();`
too to prevent default action of form submit.

Hopes these alternative help you.